# Running parent directives after children directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a page where I'd like to wait till the images have loaded before the item gets rendered into the page.

There's a [jquery plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) that I've used in the past to wait for images. It'll give you them in a callback / jquery deferred object.

The issue I was running into before was waiting for children element's directives to run. So I use `<img ng-src='values'>` because I'd prefer to avoid having the image try to hit a different server before.

The way I got it to work was via a `$timeout(fn,0)` which delays execution till the next trip around. However, I don't really like this, and think it's inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a child directive?

Comment: I meant directives on children elements. Updated.

Comment: So you're waiting for children directives to run, does that mean compile and link.

Comment: The only problems I've seen in situations with nested directives is with scope. Have you tried the code without the "wait"?